# Numpy way to integer-mask an array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, mask

I have a multi-class segmentation mask
eg.

```
[1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 2 2 2 2 4 4 4 4 4 4]
```

And going to need to get binary segmentation masks for each value

i.e.

```
[1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]

[0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0]

[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]

[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1]
```

Any elegant numpy way to do this?

Ideally an example, where I can set 0 and 1 to other values, if I have to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do "==" as this

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4])
mask1 = (a==1)*5
mask2 = (a==2)*5
mask3 = (a==3)*5
mask4 = (a==4)*5
for mask in [mask1,mask2,mask3,mask4]:
   print(mask)
```

This gives

```
[5 5 5 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 5 5 5 5 0 0 0 0 0 0 5 5 5 5 0 0 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 5 5 5 5 5 5 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 5 5 5 5 5 5]
```

You can manipulate the masks further in the same manner, i. e.

```
mask1[mask1==0] = 3
```

Answer (score 1):

**Native python approach**:

You can use comprehension and get the equality values for each unique value using `set(<sequence>)`, then convert the boolean to int to get 0,1 values.

```py
>>> ls =[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4]
>>> {v:[int(v==i) for i in ls] for v in set(ls)}

{1: [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 2: [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 3: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 4: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]}
```

**Numpy approach**:

Get the unique values for the list using `np.unique` then expand the axis and transpose the array, then expand the axis for the list also and repeat it `n` times where `n` is the number of unique values, finally do the equality comparison and convert it to integer type:

```py
import numpy as np
ls = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4]
uniques = np.expand_dims(np.unique(ls), 0).T
result = (np.repeat(np.expand_dims(ls, 0), uniques.shape[0], 0)==uniques).astype(int)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```py
print(result)
[[1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can build the mask using `np.arange` and `.repeat()` and then use broadcasting and the `==` operator to generate the arrays:

```
a = np.array([1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4])
mask = np.arange(a.min(), a.max()+1).repeat(a.size).reshape(-1, a.size)
a_masked = (a == m).astype(int)
print(a_masked.shape) # (4, 23)
print(a_masked)
# [[1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
#  [0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0]
#  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
#  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1]]
```

Setting `0` and `1` to other values can be done via normal indexing:

```
a_masked[a_masked == 0] = 7
a_masked[a_masked == 1] = 42
```